# Eliminate eval in macro using correct combination of commas and backquotes

Tags: macros, common-lisp, eval

I've written a macro that works as intended. The problem is that it contains an `eval`. I'd like to get rid of it but try as I might, I can't find the correct combination of backquotes and commas to do so.

```
(defmacro mymacro (x &body body)
  `(myothermacro ,(fun1 (eval x))
     ,@body))
```

Here `myothermacro` is a macro and `fun1` is a function.

Here is the desired behaviour:

```
(defvar v 88)

(defun fun1 (z) (1+ z))

(defmacro mymacro (x &body body)
  `(myothermacro ,(fun1 (eval x))
     ,@body))

(macroexpand-1 '(mymacro v 42 43 44)) 

    => (MYOTHERMACRO 89 42 43 44)
```

Comment: Maybe you want to tell us what you actually want to achieve. Your code looks useless - it's not clear what purpose it is for.

Comment: That's an unhelpful comment. The code shows precisely what I want to achieve. I want to achieve a macro that expands in exactly the same way as mymacro but without using eval. If you don't understand that, then please say what is unclear about it rather than dismissing it as useless.

Comment: Why would you want to eval during macroexpansion? You example does not make it clear. What is the usecase? What do you want to achieve (not what you want to do)? What is the purpose of all of this? There is very little difference between `(MYOTHERMACRO 89 42 43 44)` and `(MYOTHERMACRO v 42 43 44)`. You have replaced a variable with a macroexpansion-time value. That buys you very little.

Answer (score 3):

There is no amount of backquotes that can help you here. In a scenario you have more than one backquote there are equally as many quasiquote and thus you can get different layers of quoted data but not data evaluated more than once.

It's important to understand that a macro does not do anything runtime. Thus if you are to use a macro eg `(mymacro variable (my-function x))` the macro function `mymacro` is fed `variable` and `(my-function x)` right away and the result in put in place. `variable` might not exist yet so evaluating it would be premature. When you define a function that uses the macro it will most likely expand the macros before storing the function. When in runtime there are no macros because they are all expanded, but this is the very first time it's possible to make conclusions if the arguments passed to the macro and its expansion actually makes sense according to the lexical environment and global bindings.

Perhaps if you added more information would there be a way to help you solve your actual problem since I get a feeling this is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Thanks for your helpful reply and for your reference to XY problems. I will edit my question to add some additional information and hopefully clarify it. My assumption was that it would be possible during macroexpansion to evaluate `x` and then evaluate `fun1` of the value of `x`. If this assumption is wrong, then `eval` is inevitable.

Comment: @user3414663 Why do you need `v` evaluated. In runtime later `v` will still be `88`? Thus a perfectly good expansion would be `(MYOTHERMACRO (fun1 v) 42 43 44)`

Comment: I simplified my example to its core. In my application `v` is an sexp which `myothermacro` in turn expands. This all happens at compile time.

Comment: Are you sure that a macro does not do anything at 'runtime'? What about a Common Lisp interpreter?

Comment: @RainerJoswig You are right in making the behaviour implementation specific. An implementation have lots of options on how to do stuff, but I think macros are most surprising for beginners when they get expanded even before a function gets used. Side effects in macros are a mess.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use use read-time evaluation if I got your idea right.
Something like this:

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (defparameter *foo* "foo"))

(defmacro bar (arg)
  `(list #.*foo* ,arg))

CL-USER> (macroexpand '(bar "bar"))
         (LIST "foo" "bar")
```

You may be better with defconstant instead of defparameter because it's clearer about intentions.